# Excel powerpivot, show when the data was updated?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have an Excel sheet with powerpivot tables and charts. I want to show when the data was updated.

I use VBA code and a button to update the data, and I use the function now() in a cell which is updated when the code is running.

I have two problems.

- When I open the Excel file the date is updated even if I do not update the data on start. (I do not want the data to update on start)
- When the update fails the date is still updated.

My VBA code look like this:

```
Range("table name").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.refresh
Range("date cell").Select
```

How to avoid update when the data is not updated?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solve it as user3819867 suggested, I solved it by adding the information from the database, which is a SQL server database so I added a view with one colum and one row (with a getdate()) and send it along with the other tables so I get one extra table named "date".

Answer (score 0):

How about its event?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable) 
Range("date cell").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me solve one of the problem, update date when update fails :) but it stil update the date when I open the excel file.

Comment: That's a property that has nothing to do with VBA disable it at [your Pivot's settings](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Update-refresh-data-in-a-PivotTable-d3f74ee2-0da7-4aef-8b2f-481bb2f18218).

Comment: Ok, that might work, I solved it in a different way. Instead of letting excel determine the date for the update I send the date from the server along with the data.